# How do I prevent loading the same image multiple times when generating elements?

Tags: javascript, html, image, server, lazy-loading

I have a script that generates product "cards" on my website. These product cards contain images of the products. When they initially load, they have tiny-sized placeholder images to indicate that the actual product images are still loading (lazy-loading).

However, when I check the network activity, the placeholder image [*blank.gif*] is being downloaded and re-downloaded for every instance of it on the page. This impacts the loading of the page, which cuts into the time saved with the lazy-load script.

[screenshot of images loading in the network tab of dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMTZd.png)

Currently, the cards' HTML is assembled into a variable then it's appended to its respective place in the body of the page's HTML, one at a time. *See Below*

How can I make it so that the image only loads from the server once, and shows up in the multitude of places it belongs?

Card Code:

```
    // Simplified for Stack Exchange
    // A JSON file contains activeCards which this script pulls data from

    var cardImgs = '';

    for (let i of activeCards) {

        cardImgs = "<img class='soloImg' src='images/blank.gif' data-src='images/" + i.img + "' alt='" + i.imgAlt + "' />";

        // Builds card HTML from elements above
        card = "<div class='card' id='" + i.id + "'>" +
            "<div class='cardImagesCont'>" + cardImgs + "</div>" +
            "<h2>" + i.title + "</h2>" +
            "<h4 class='itemDesc'>" + i.description + "</h4></div>";

        // Adds card to section
        $('.cardSection').append(card);
    }
```

Lazy Load Code:

```
function lazyload() { 
    for (let i of $('img[data-src]')) {
        $(i).attr('src', $(i).attr('data-src'));
    }
}
```

I'm self-taught, so please don't be too cruel if there's something shockingly wrong with this code (but do let me know)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON

Comment: Maybe your web server is not sending HTML 304 response codes for the image directory.  Also, this does not answer your question, but I notice `blank.gif` is pretty big; 128 KB.  Maybe make it a 1x1 pixel image?

Comment: Also, I note you are on localhost. When you are developing on localhost the images will not disk cache, but actually on you live site the browser will cache these replicated images. Does that make sense. Try running through ngrok.io

Comment: Mark, the blank.gif is an animated graphic that indicates loading. It's as small as it can be while achieving that goal. But I understand where you're coming from.
Bibberty, I think you may be right, Doing further testing on the actual server instead of localhost, the image loads once. Thanks!